# Integração MongoDB com ASP.NET MVC 5 e PostgreSQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postgresql, arquitetura-de-software, mongodb

Estou construindo um projeto em ASP.NET MVC 5 com banco de dados PostgreSQL, neste banco existe uma tabela de histórico que crescerá em cerca de **500 mil linhas** por mês e teremos relatórios que pegarão dados de períodos de um ano.
Então pensamos em utilizar o MongoDb para esta tabela específica e todo o restante do banco seria com PostgreSQL.
Visto que teremos um performance bem maior nesta tabela usando MongoDb.

Vale a pena utilizar este tipo de arquitetura com PostgreSQL e MongoDb no mesmo projeto?
Se sim, qual a melhor forma de fazer e quais ferramentas?
Se não, qual o método mais apropriado?

Answer (score 2):

> Vale a pena utilizar este tipo de arquitetura com PostgreSQL e MongoDb no mesmo projeto?

Se seu projeto realmente trabalhar com dados relacionais e não relacionais, vale muito a pena sim. E aparentemente, para seu fim, é bem apropriado.

> Se sim, qual a melhor forma de fazer e quais ferramentas?

Parece que será seu primeiro contato com MongoDb, certo? Recomendo esse [curso de introdução ao MongoDB](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/mongodb-introduction/table-of-contents). Me ajudou bastante no meu primeiro contato. E para recuperar os dados, vc pode sincronizar os dados com um ElasticSearch com Kibana.

> Se não, qual o método mais apropriado?

É sempre o arquiteto do software quem deve tomar essas decisões. Se vc é o cara que está desenhando o sistema, é vc quem deve decidir. Brinque um pouco com bases NoSQL como MongoDB, e vc irá descobrir um mundo novo de possibilidades e quebras de alguns limites, claro que tudo isso junto com a quebra de vários paradigmas.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta